# Google Compute Engine CPU usage stuck at 30%

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I'm running one instance of 2 vCPUs, 1.8 GB. I'm trying to use more computing power but am stuck at 30% and can't find any usage quota for CPU usage, on number of CPUs I can use. Is there a way to use all 100%, or at least more than 30%?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My VMs may have daily spikes to 100% of CPU usage or even more, depending on the traffic i'm getting. There is no cap at 30%. The cap of 100% starts after several minutes of exceeding the 100% cap. So the system is quite flexible.

As for being stuck at 30%, it may be a script running on the server that's consuming exactly this amount of processing power. It's very hard to assess why this is happening not knowing the nature or the scope of your VM.

If you think 30% shouldn't be there, it may be the case that you have a zombie process. Use the **top** command to check the processes running.

Comment: Thanks, it was a zombie process put in place to limit my CPU usage.

Comment: @zoltar can you elaborate on this zombie process limiting CPU usage? I'm having the same problem when I try to perform multithreading on vCPUs...

Answer (score 0):

there can be a possibility that you have not configured the ulimit max proc configuration for the user which the process is grouped under. To check the ulimit for the user switch to the user you wanna checkout then use `ulimit -n`. if you see it lower than the expected then you can change the limit from `/etc/security/limits.conf` For more detailed information you can refer: [link](https://scott.cm/max-processes-1024-limits-conf/)